# How can the final /r/ in 'razor' and 'hammer' be syllabic?

Tags: phonology, syllabic-consonants

I just learned liquid /l,r/ become syllabic when at the end of a word and immediately after a consonant. When I look at examples such as paddle and whistle, I can understand /l/ in those words becomes syllabic. But I don't understand the case of final /r/ in razor and hammer. Razor and hammer in IPA have schwa which is nucleus, then how can /r/ in 'razor' and 'hammer' be syllabic?

Answer (score 10):

The source citing *razor* and *hammer* as examples of a syllabic /r/ is using a different analysis than the one transcribing them with a final /ə(r)/ (my choice of notation here is so as to remain agnostic as to whether we are considering rhotic or non-rhotic dialects, which would have /ər/ & /ə/ respectively).

Especially in American English where /ər/ is typically realised as [ɚ] (which is phonetically almost identical to [ɻ]) it is natural to analyse this as a single segment that is phonemically a syllabic /r/.

Note that similar differences in analysis can apply to words like *paddle* & *whistle* which are sometimes transcribed ending in final /əl/ rather than a syllabic /l/.

The fact that the ⟨l⟩ is orthographically next to the preceding consonant, and the ⟨r⟩ is not, is purely an artefact of the spelling, and not reflective of any phonetic or phonological difference between the two examples.

Comment: "The source citing razor and hammer as example of a syllabic r is using a different analysis than the one transcribing them with a final /ə(r)/" <-- Well, hmm, not really. They are describing different varieties of English. The word-final syllabic /r/ description is of a rhotic variety. The /ə(r)/ transcription device is used solely for non-rhotic varieties.

Comment: @Araucaria-him: I always understood the /ə(r)/ transcription as intended to cover both rhotic and non-rhotic varieties together — that’s why it marks the /r/ as optional.  So as you say, part of the difference is about which varieties of English they’re aiming to cover — but part also is that it’s analysing them as /hæmər/ for rhotic varieties, as opposed to /hæmr/ in the other transcription.  That’s the sort of subtle difference can arise either from describing different varieties of a language, or from having different analyses of the same variety.

Comment: @PLL Hi, no, that's not what the /ə(r)/ transcription is for! The /r/ is not optional in the rhotic varieties, and the /r/ is not pronounceable in the non-rhotic varieties apart from in certain environments when it ***must*** be pronounced. If you look in a good dictionary, you'll see that they give a description for the standard UK and US varieties. They don't give a blend of the two! Standard American ('General American') is rhotic and standard British ('RP' or 'SSBE' ) is non-rhotic. You'll only see /ə(r)/, sometimes written with a superscript non-bracketed  r , in the British transcription

Comment: @PLL In the British transcription this does not indicate that the /r/ is optional. It means that if there is no immediately following vowel, the /r/ is not pronounced, and if there is one, it is. So, for example, we see *car* pronounced without an /r/ in *car park*, but with an /r/ in *car alarm.*  This is quite different therefore from where we see a schwa in brackets (or in superscript) in a transcription. In the latter case the schwa is indeed optional. But in the case of /ə(r)/ the presence or absence of the /r/ is not optional but it determined by the environment.

Comment: @PLL The upshot of which is that the /ə(r)/ description does not apply to the variety described by the OP. It is not a 'different' analysis of the phonetics or phonology, just a description of a completely different variety of English.

Comment: @Araucaria-him the /ə(r)/ _is_ intended to cover both rhotic and non-rhotic varieties. It is implicitly /ə/ in non-rhotic varieties and /ər/ (which is then often realised as [ɚ]) in rhotic ones. The (r) could also be used in non-rhotic varieties to notate the possibility of a linking r, but I have never seen this done when talking specifically about non-rhotic varieties, and I have never seen an (r) included where an intrusive r would be compulsory (e.g. I have only ever seen "law" transcribed /lɔ:/ never /lɔ:(r)/, occasionally with the ":" ommitted)

Comment: I do agree that in general giving two transcriptions is better and that dictionaries tend to do this, but that's irrelevant to the answer

Comment: @Tristan Can you find any authoritative source that uses /ə(r)/ to cover both varieties? A dictionary, for example? Or a text book? I rather think not! ;-) There is no /ə(r)/ analysis of the OP's described words! [There's also a substantial difference between the /l/ and /r/ situations (because /l/ is not coarticulated in the same way; you don't get /l/-coloured vowels in Gen Am). /l/-has it's own vocalic resonance depending on its place in the syllable]

Comment: @Araucaria-him Muthmann's Reverse English Dictionary: Based on Phonological and Morphological Principles from Brill does exactly this. Most other dictionaries are focussed primarily on a particular norm (either British or American) and so follow norms that are less dialect-agnostic. Regardless, I have never seen this notation used when discussing solely non-rhotic varieties (to indicate a possible linking or intrusive r) as you suggest it is solely used for in your first comment. I will add a clarifying note about my intentions using this notation though

Comment: How, in any meaningful sense, can you say that a non-rhotic pronunciation of *razor* differs only in analysis from a rhotic one with a syllabic r???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141199/discussion-between-tristan-and-araucaria-him).

Answer (score 3):

There are competing theories of transcription, not because of fundamental disagreements as to the meanings of the letters or what the facts are (though there are plenty of factual disagreements). Differences in transcription especially for English are largely because of differences of analysis – what does a transcription represent? One end of the continuum is that it should represent how a particular utterance is pronounced, therefore it is a symbolic representation of the information that you would get from a spectrogram or some physiology-inspecting gadget. The other end is that is represents the phonological analysis assumed (and hopefully justified) by the transcriber. As you move towards the abstract-analysis end of the scale, there is also the question of what level of analysis one assumes, for example is it a relatively shallow analysis that only looks at utterances in isolation (focusing on minimal pairs and complementary distribution), or does it look for deeper regularities, embodied in the underlying forms of words.

There are many ways to transcribe the vowels of "take" and "tech", restricting oneself to just IPA letters, including at least [e: e], [e: ɛ], [eɪ e], [eɪ ɛ], [ɛi e], [ɛi ɛ], [ɛɪ e], [ɛɪ ɛ], and [e ɛ]. The transcription of syllabic sonorants is another (less-variable) case. In the case of syllabic *r*, this variation is encouraged by the existence of special symbols or combinations [ɚ] and [ɝ] in the IPA, for which there is no parallel w.r.t. lateral articulation. One might write [əɹ], [ɚ], [ɝ], [ɹ̩] without greatly offending the phonetic implications of the IPA (whereas writing [æʀ] is phonetically misleading for American and British English).

Given various ways to transcribe the final syllable of "powder" and "poodle", the primary question is whether, for each word, we should write a vowel-plus consonant sequence, or a single segment. The answer depends on what kind to facts you are trying to convey – something about physical production, or something about abstract analysis? At the physical level, the primary question is whether there is an identifiable vowel between the stop and the final liquid. Not all speakers of English (even American English) are the same. I don't have a vowel transition in my speech, but in the case of following /l/, some people (from Ohio) do.

There are good phonological reasons to posit that syllabic [ɹ̩, l̩, m̩, n̩] can derive from /Vr, Vl, Vm, Vn/ in English, given stress alternations and stress-dependent reduction to schwa. But we can also determine that orthographic "e" is actually phonologically lacking in "rotten" (therefore, [n̩] and not [ən]) because /t/ becomes [ʔ] when immediately before [n,n̩]. This argument doesn't hold for southern dialects with [rɔɾən] i.e. flapping and a more-obvious vowel.